# What is a type $\text{II}_1$ factor von Neumann algebra?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

After finding formal definitions in various texts (see, eg, Witten, *Notes On Some Entanglement Properties Of Quantum Field Theory*, Rev. Mod. Phys. 90, 45003 (2018), doi:[10.1103/RevModPhys.90.045003](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.90.045003) arXiv:[1803.04993](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993)), I have ($\text I$) not been able to obtain a good intuition for them and ($\text{II}_1$) have not seen anyone relate such factors to more commonly understood Hilbert spaces such as $L^2(\mathbb R)$. This is very likely for good reason, but it would be nice to have these ideas come down from the clouds so that one can present them to non-mathematicians and (maybe this is too ambitious) laypeople.

Some more technical sources which helped me answer this are [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371383/what-is-a-type-textii-1-factor-von-neumann-algebra) and [here](https://www.math.ku.dk/english/research/conferences/what_is/a_II_1_factor.pdf).

Comment: You say that you "have not seen anyone relate such factors to more commonly understood Hilbert spaces". This phrasing suggests you think that factors are examples of Hilbert spaces? If so, that is already a misconception

Comment: Moreover, it is not clear what "intuition" is supposed to mean here. What algebraic objects of a similar nature have you encountered? Obviously there is no point trying to say that two-one factors are analogues of simple groups, if you are not already familiar with results about simple groups. But if you are familiar with examples of simple and non-simple groups then one can start to explain what von Neumann factors are, and then one can try to say something about what makes two-one factors special

Comment: @YemonChoi one could be charitable and guess the OP meant how one could see $II_1$ factors as having canonical representations on certain Hilbert spaces arising from other known structures. But I agree it's not worded that way.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Fair enough. For what it's worth, I am not sure why the OP is linking to a paper of Witten as their example of a formal definition of a two-one factor. The Wikipedia page on von Neumann algebras is actually fairly good at leading up to the definition of a factor and then the classification result of Murray and von Neumann https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra

Comment: @Yemon I agree. One can at minimum chase the WP definition chain to at least get an idea of what objects are involved, and what examples to look at. I was going to suggest von Neumann's original work, which of course was motivated by physics, but I imagine it's low on intuition based on decades of experience, as a modern survey would be!

Comment: Sorry all for posting such a vague question. I've looked into it a little, and wrote up something that I think could help the people I had in mind. Feel free to let me know any more thoughts.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what the question here hopes to achieve: the updated version has a link to a short set of notes which gives the basic definitions, and to my eyes as a mathematician those notes are more accurate than the answer you've written for your own question. It seems like you want someone to write a version of the standard definition which uses the language/perspective of quantum information theory; but what you've written below has many imprecisions/errors from a mathematician's point of view

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not enough effort has been put in by the proposer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider first the usual Fock space (countably $\infty$-dim vector space) whose basis states $|n\rangle$ are labeled by nonnegative integers $n\geq 0$. This space admits what are called *minimal projections*: matrices $|n\rangle\langle n|$ which serve as the fundamental building blocks of all matrices that are diagonal in this basis. These building blocks are trace one, and cannot be further divided into sums of two other projections which have lower trace. The presence of such minimal projections implies that any von Neumann algebra on this space is of Type I.

Now consider a tensor product space of $n$ qubits (the vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$) with $n$ being arbitrarily large, and with allowed operators acting nontrivially only on a finite subset of the qubits. Such a space does not admit a minimal projection. Consider a projection

$$
\Pi = |0\rangle\langle0|^{\otimes k}\otimes I^{\otimes (n-k)}
$$

onto the basis state $|0\rangle\langle 0|$ for the first $k$ qubits and identity $I$ on the remaining $n-k$. The trace of this projection is $2^{n-k}$. It is not minimal because we can resolve the identity on the $k+1^{\text{st}}$ qubit and construct projections (with $\ell\in\{0,1\}$)

$$
\Pi_{\ell} = |0\rangle\langle0|^{\otimes k}\otimes |\ell\rangle\langle\ell|\otimes|0\rangle\langle0|^{\otimes (n-k-1)}
$$

that have smaller trace and sum up to $\Pi$. The lack of a minimal projection makes this space a candidate for housing Type II factors.

This ability to always resolve identities of other qubits allows us to keep cutting up projections into finer and finer pieces. This difference between the two spaces reminds me of the fact that any positive real number can always be expressed as a sum of two other positive reals, while there exists an element of the integers (namely, $1$) that cannot be expressed as a sum of two positive integers.

Comment: Many of the mathematical definitions/concepts mentioned here are being used in ways that seem to differ from how an "orthodox" functional analyst would use them. For a start, any Hilbert space admits "minimal projections", they just might not be of the form that you are thinking of

Comment: To maybe make more clear what Yemon Choi said already: There seems to be a crucial misunderstanding of the role of the Hilbert space. Whether or not there are minimal projections really depends on which projection you "choose" to belong to the von Neumann algebra, not which projections exist on the underlying Hilbert space. Of course there are $\text{II}_1$ factors that can be faithfully represented on the Fock space, in fact, every separable $\text{II}_1$ factor can.

Comment: @MaoWao thanks, this helps. Let me see if I understand. One can embed the space of $n$-qubits into a $2^n$-dim Fock space, meaning that the above projections can also be constructed there. So one should not focus on the Hilbert space when constructing these various factors.